# How to fail when bean annotated with javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped

Tags: jsf, cdi

Is there a way of detecting `@Named` CDI-Beans which are created with `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped`? It happened multiple times to me, that the IDE preferred this annotation to `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped`.

Is there a good way to just abort the application startup when a `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped` annotated CDI-Bean is found?

Answer (score 4):

> *Is there a good way to just abort the application startup when a `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped` annotated CDI-Bean is found?*

Yes! You can use a [CDI extension](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/extend.html) for this as long as you've a `bean-discovery-mode="all"`.

Here's a kickoff example tailored for your specific use case:

```java
package com.stackoverflow.q76653269;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.ProcessAnnotatedType;

public class BadBeansDetector implements Extension {

    <T> void processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<T> type) {
        Set<Class<?>> badBeans = new HashSet<>();

        if (type.getAnnotatedType().getAnnotation(javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped.class) != null) {
            badBeans.add(type.getAnnotatedType().getJavaClass());
        }
        
        if (!badBeans.isEmpty()) {
            throw new DeploymentException("Bad beans found! " + badBeans);
        }
    }
}
```

To get it to run, create a `META-INF/services/javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension` text file with the sole content:

```
com.stackoverflow.q76653269.BadBeansDetector
```

In case of a Maven WAR project, this `META-INF` folder must reside in `src/main/resources` (and thus not `src/main/webapp`).

In case you've `bean-discovery-mode="annotated"`, then this won't work, but the bad bean would in first place not be injectable and already block deployment with an unsatisfied dependency exception anywhere you `@Inject` it and you wouldn't need to ask this question.

The alternative is of course to upgrade to JSF 2.3 where this annotation is marked `@Deprecated` and reconfigure your build/compiler to fail when a deprecated thing is encountered. Yet another alternative is to migrate further to Faces 4.0 where this deprecated annotation is long removed ;)

Comment: The suggested approach is good but note that it doesn't need to notify you of all such beans - the reason is that CDI won't fire `ProcessAnnotatedType` for non-bean types and the set of those is determined by chosen discovery mode. If there is a class bearing just `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped` annotation (and no other bean defining annotation), you will not detect it via this extension if you have `annotated` discovery mode. However, in  such a case you're likely going to see an unsatisfied dependency error if you try to inject it anywhere.

Comment: @Siliarus: Fair enough. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think the previous answer is just fine, but another way to catch this at compile time would be to use the Maven Enforcer plugin: https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/usage.html

Then use this rule extensions that can search for banned class usages: https://github.com/skuzzle/restrict-imports-enforcer-rule

The total change in your pom.xml would be something like:

```
...
<build>
 <plugins>
...

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.skuzzle.enforcer</groupId>
            <artifactId>restrict-imports-enforcer-rule</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>check-viewscopedjsf-imports</id>
            <phase>process-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <RestrictImports>
                        <reason>Use CDI managed beans, not deprecated JSF APIs</reason>
                        <bannedImport>javax.faces.bean.**</bannedImport>
                    </RestrictImports>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
```

The advantage of this approach is you'll catch the error while compiling, instead of while running, so it may save you a bit of time depending on your use case. I don't think this will check third party libraries however, which BalusC's solution would do. So  if this is a big problem in your stack, you could probably run both solutions for full coverage.